# Ionic tab background color

Tags: jquery, angularjs, html, css, ionic-framework

[image: Please refer to this image]

Hi,
I am using Ionic to develop a mobile app. I used Ionic tabs template. On the bottom of the screen, the background of tab is still white. I don't know how to change the background. I am only change the color of the icon with the following code. How can I change the background tab color.

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-{{theme.primary}}" > 
      <ion-tab title="Cards" icon-off="ion-ios-pulse" icon-on="ion-ios-pulse-strong" href="#/tab/dash">
          <ion-nav-view name="tab-dash"> 
          </ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem and I did not get any solution that worked.

My home solution in app.scss:

```css
.tabbar {
    background: red !important;
    color: #bbb !important;
    & .tab-button {
        color: #bbb !important;
        & .tab-button-icon {
            color: #bbb !important;

        }

    }
    & .tab-button[aria-selected=true]{
        // text-shadow: 1px 0px #eaeaea;
        color: white !important;
        & .tab-button-icon {
            text-shadow: 1px 0px #eaeaea;
            color: white !important;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `tabs-background-positive` class

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-{{theme.primary}} tabs-background-positive" > 
      <ion-tab title="Cards" icon-off="ion-ios-pulse" icon-on="ion-ios-pulse-strong" href="#/tab/dash">
          <ion-nav-view name="tab-dash"> 
          </ion-nav-view>
      </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add other ionic color class too such as -

1. light - white color
2. stable - light grey color
3. assertive - red color
4. calm - light blue color
5. dark - black color
6. energised - yellow color
7. royal  - violet color
8. balanced - green color

Just replace "tabs-background-positive" with above options.

Comment: What if you want the tabs background to be black?

Comment: you can add the class -dark (already mentioned in the above list)

Comment: dark is not black

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue, **getting rid of `color`** in `tabs-color-royal` along with options already provided by Aman did the trick!

```html
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-{{theme.primary}}">
  <ion-tab title="Cards" icon-off="ion-ios-pulse" icon-on="ion-ios-pulse-strong" href="#/tab/dash">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-dash">
    </ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

**Options:**

- royal
- light
- stable
- assertive
- calm
- dark
- energised
- balanced

Answer (score 0):

```
ion-tab-bar, ion-tab-button{
  background-color: #320d99;
  color: #fff;
 }

 ion-icon{
   color: #ffffff;

 }
```

it works...

Comment: please consider explaining what you did. Only code answers are considered as low quality, though it is okay.